# How about taking out Bootstrap style?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Firstly, I don't have much experience with Bootstrap and I just started my second Bootstrap project. Sometimes I confused about overriding CSS. It may spend more time to find out the style need to be changed rather than write from scratch. So I am thinking... how about taking out the bootstrap style?

For example, keep the markup structure, set the `color` `background`, `font` value to `inherit`, remove all shadows, gradients, `border`, `border-radius` etc.. Furthermore, build a reference in order to check the default value easily. Then we can just use the layout of Bootstrap but write our own style.

I prefer to not directly modify the Bootstrap source code. Use an extra CSS file is better to organise. It is also good to update Bootstrap.

By the way, I really miss the [blankwork grid system](https://github.com/justnorris/Blankwork-Flexible-SASS-Grid-System), is it possible to add this feature into Bootstrap?

So, do you think this is a good idea or bad?

Comment: I think you can make use of CSS's cascade and define blank rules after the bootstrap ones, or just not include those files...

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/twitter-bootstrap would be a more appropriate place for this.

Comment: you could download the bootstrap less files (uncompiled css files) and alter those, it would probably take less time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is possibly the customised version of bootstrap.  See the details at http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/customize.html.  This will allow you to pick which elements of bootstrap framework you would like to use without adding the other parts.  It also allows you to customise fonts and some basic shades and colours.

This can also be done via the less system - see http://bootstrap.lesscss.ru/less.html for information on how to do this.

And finally, if you are having trouble identifying which css is being applied to which element, have you tried using a browser debug tool such as Firebug in firefox?

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I wish I could use bootstrap as using the CSS reset. So I stated this project http://peters-playground.com/Blank-Bootstrap/index.html, please take a look :)

Comment: That is one way to proceed, but I would recommend keeping the LESS aspects as it allows easier customisation.  For example, if I wanted my danger buttons to be a different colour then it would be easier for me to specify this using less, rather than having to edit your css by hand.  In addition, there are other CSS Frameworks that might suit your needs if you are having to customise Bootstrap to such an extent.

Comment: Thanks Kami. Just one more question, if you have two or three different danger buttons (suppose they look quite differently) in one project how will you organize them? Will you change the default style in LESS files, and override each style again? or there is a better way to approach. I cannot figure this out. I would appreciate if you can give me some advices.

Comment: I dont quite follow.  If you have 3 buttons named the same, they would override each other.  If you have different names then they become different names and can be treated as bootstrap currently treats other buttons (eg, info, primary, warning etc).

Comment: Suppose I have two buttons (or other elements), both of them have class `.btn-danger` because they have the same meaning, but they look differently. Normally I will do `#div_one .btn-danger` and `#div_two .btn-danger` to define their styles. I think that I am overriding the default styles too many times, so I'd like to have a blank bootstrap. and I cannot see how to use the bootstrap LESS file to make it easy.

Comment: In bootstrap, `btn` class is used to define a basic button, with each of the other classes providing additional information.  If you have buttons that have different look, they should have different names rather than depending on how they are invoked.  The examples you give are customisation specific to your requirements and probably will not translate well to other users.